# Variable selection methods for big sparse data in R with many NULL values

Tags: r, bigdata, na, decision-tree

I am working with datasets with at least 100K rows and at least 10K variables. There are a considerable amount of NULL values. Most of the variables are numeric with a handful being categorical.

I want to use something like randomForest for variable selection, but of course the NAs are a problem.

What are some robust variable selection methods for such data?

Comment: Maybe you should transform your data before training a regression tree on it.

Comment: I would do a simple type of imputation (say, with the mean of a group of interest or something that simple) and then find some latent variables and see what happens. Worst come to worst do a lasso on da thing

Comment: Karsten, could you be more specific?

animalito, I am in the process of using rfImpute but it is crashing everytime on my dataset. Do you recommend other robust and automated imputation packages for large data. Also, any thoughts on the validity of imputation on sparse data?

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot add a comment, I'll try to answer... I'm working with similar type of data than you. What I do is to work with the data first in long format and calculating contingency tables for each "potential predictor", I use a filter feature selection method to select good predictors for my dataset. I'll try to put an example:

- Long format data:

ID|PREDICTOR|PREDICTOR_VALUE|CLASS

1 |PRED_1   |3              |0

2 |PRED_1   |1              |1

2 |PRED_2   |2              |1

So as you can see, if you put the data in wide format, you'll get a NULL in case ID=1 for PRED_2.

Using the data in long format, I calculate for each predictor a contingency table with the frequencies they appear for each class and I use that to calculate for example the Information Gain. Then, I rank the predictors using the values of the Information Gain. Then, it's up to you to select the first 100 or 1000 or whatever number predictors from that list. Once you select them, you can convert the data in wide format. You probably will still have some missing values but then you could either use imputation as they suggest in the comment above or for instance, in my case since I work with frequencies, if a predictor does not appear for a case, I'll just put 0. 
I hope this has helped or at least provide some ideas on how to approach the problem...